# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: No public static field named [ShoppingBag] was found on class [Others.Customer]

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp from which I am accessing a property called shoppingbag of a java bean called Customer . But unfortunately whenever I run my jsp I get this exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: No public static field named [ShoppingBag] was found on class [Others.Customer]
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: No public static field named [ShoppingBag] was found on class [Others.Customer]
javax.el.StaticFieldELResolver.getValue(StaticFieldELResolver.java:61)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:936)
org.apache.jsp.Header_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(Header_jsp.java:249)
org.apache.jsp.Header_jsp._jspService(Header_jsp.java:167)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:934)
org.apache.jsp.MainPage_jsp._jspService(MainPage_jsp.java:107)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is My JSP

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" >WOMEN <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="AbdulTayyebs?ID=201">Tops </a></li>
        <li><a href="AbdulTayyebs?ID=202">Shirts </a></li>
        <li><a href="AbdulTayyebs?ID=203">Trousers & Jeans </a></li>
        <li><a href="AbdulTayyebs?ID=204">Inner Wears </a></li>
        <li><a href="AbdulTayyebs?ID=205">Leggings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" >KIDS<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li  role ="presentation" class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" ><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" ></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
          <c:if test="${Customer!=null}">
              <li><a href="Billing.jsp">Shopping Cart <span class="badge">
               ***${Customer.ShoppingBag.Size}***   
                      </span> </a></li>   
          </c:if>
          <c:if test="${Customer==null}">
          <li><a href="Billing.jsp">Shopping Cart <span class="badge">${0}</span> </a></li>
          </c:if>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="AbdulTayyebs?">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" width="200" placeholder="Search" name="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
  </form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us </a></li>
    <c:if test="${Logged == false or Logged==null}">
    <li><a href="Signup.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li></c:if>     
    <c:if test="${Logged!=null}">
    <c:if test="${Logged==true}">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" >${Customer.getFirstname()}<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="Profile.jsp"> View Profile </a></li>
        <li><a href="AbdulTayyebs?ViewAddress=true"> Add/Remove Address </a></li>
        <li><a href="ChangePassword.jsp"> Update Password </a></li>
        <li><a href="AbdulTayyebs?GetOrders=true"> My Orders </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="AbdulTayyebs?Action=Logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
    </c:if>
    </c:if>
    </ul>
 </div> 
</nav>
```

And here is my class Customer

```
public class Customer extends User implements java.io.Serializable{
private String password;
private ArrayList <PurchaseableItem> ShoppingBag;
private ArrayList <String> WishList;;

public Customer() {
 super();   
 ShoppingBag=null;
 WishList=null;
}
public String getPassword() { return password; }

public ArrayList<String> getWishList() { return WishList; }

public void setWishList(ArrayList<String> WishList) { this.WishList =    WishList; }

public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

public ArrayList<PurchaseableItem> getShoppingBag(){ return this.ShoppingBag; }

public void setShoppingBag(ArrayList<PurchaseableItem> ShoppingBag) { this.ShoppingBag = ShoppingBag; }

public void AddToShoppingBag(ArrayList<PurchaseableItem> ShoppingBag){
  if(ShoppingBag!=null){
   if(this.ShoppingBag==null){
    this.ShoppingBag = new ArrayList<>();
    }    
   for(PurchaseableItem prc:ShoppingBag)
    this.ShoppingBag.add(prc);
 }
 }

 public int TotalItems(){
 return ShoppingBag.size(); 
 }
}
```

I am not able understand why this error is occurring.It would be highly appreciable if anybody can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're shooting yourself in the foot by not respecting the Java naming conventions. They're quite simple:

- packages are named in lowercase. So the package `Others` should be named `others`.
- variables, including fields, are camelCased. So `ShoppingBag` should be named `shoppingBag`, and `WishList` should be named `wishList`.
- methods are camelCased. So `AddToShoppingBag()` should be named `addToShoppingBag()`.
- When you have a getter named `getShoppingBag()`, the corresponding bean property is named `shoppingBag`, not `ShoppingBag`. And the JSP EL is used to access bean properties. So , to call `customer.getShoppingBag()` from the JSP EL, you use `${customer.shoppingBag}`, not `${customer.ShoppingBag}`.
- page, request, session and application attributes are named like local variables, in camelCase. So you should never have `${Customer}`, but always `${customer}`.

Respect these Java conventions, and everything will go much better, your code will be consistent, and your collegues won't feel like killing you.